# Detect statically added QML children from c++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.6

QML code:

```
MyItem {
    Item {
        id: exampleChild
    }
}
```

c++ code:

```
class MyItem : public QQuickItem {
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    void QObject::childEvent(QChildEvent* event) override {
        qDebug() << "This is never fired when exampleChild is added.";
    }
};
```

Here is an old discussion about this that went nowhere: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.qml/1677

How can the addition of these statically declared items be detected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override [`QQuickItem::itemChange()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#itemChange) and handle `QQuickItem::ItemChildAddedChange`. Don't forget to call the base class implementation of `itemChange()`.

Comment: Yes, this works. I think it is worthwhile to also mention that the added child must be based on `QQuickItem`; `QObject` based children are still not recognized.